# How to programmatically configure IIS7? (without using the Metabase)

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7

Consider a .NET application that performs lots of configuration changes in IIS such as changing Virtual Directories or enabling compression. With IIS6 everything could be accomplished using the metabase through `DirectoryServices`.

However in IIS7, the Metabase compatiblity is an optional component, so I'm assuming that alternative ways should be used in order to programmatically perform configuration changes. What's the right way of doing those? Should I directly edit the `applicationHost.config` file or is there a recommended API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe [Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.aspx) has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use :

- the [WebAdministration PowerShell](http://www.iis.net/extensions/PowerShell) Addin, in PowerShell.
- the [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/165/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration/) class, from .NET code.