# Can a console application return the web (external) url for a local folder in c#/.net?

Tags: c#, .net, url, web, path

We have a requirement to auto-fill a field in the database for a customer's specific installation of our web application. We already have a console app to help with some configurations during install. It is located in the root folder of the web application. Is there any way it can take this physical server path and find the registered URL?

e.g.: Run the console app in c://inetpub/wwwroot/client/application and have it return http://www.example.com/application

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512522/how-to-programmatically-configure-iis7-without-using-the-metabase

Comment: This blog post looks like it might help as well...https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2011/01/21/get-iis-bindings-at-runtime-without-being-an-administrator/